# Issue with onStopRecord Function in React Native Audio Recorder Player library

Tags: react-native, audio-recording

```
// Import the required library
import AudioRecorderPlayer from "react-native-audio-recorder-player";



// Function to stop recording (issue here)
const onStopRecord = React.useCallback(async () => {
  try {
    // Issue occurs within this function
    const result = await audioRecorderPlayer.stopRecorder();
    audioRecorderPlayer.removeRecordBackListener();
    setRecordSecs(0);
    console.log(result);
    console.log(result, "Recorder result");
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error stopping recorder:", error);
  }
}, []);
```

I am encountering a problem with the `onStopRecord` function when using the React Native Audio Recorder Player library. Specifically, I am unable to stop the recording properly, and I'm seeking guidance on resolving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting issue from this line:-

```
const audioRecorderPlayer = new AudioRecorderPlayer();
```

I declared it inside of my class, but it should be declare in outside of class, This solved my issue of onstoprecord and onstopplay not working.